# Why does the result of printf number change when include tab?

Tags: c, printf

The below code show wrong result for 44 and 84.

[image]

So, I tried to change \t into space and the numbers were shown correctly as shown below.

[image]

Why just having tab in printf cause the number to be print incorrectly?
I have tried to change 4 into 7 and 8 and the same problem occurred.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int count = 1; count <= 100 ; ++count)
    {
        if((count % 4) == 0 )
            printf("%d\t", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int count = 1; count <= 100 ; ++count)
    {
        if((count % 4) == 0 )
            printf("%d ", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A [MCVE] must include the code as *text*, in the *body* of the question. Please edit it in and remove the links to outside resources.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to add image.

Comment: You cannot post code in an image. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why.  Code is text, and should be copied and pasted directly into your question as such.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to add code.

Comment: I suspect a strange line wrapping in the output window. Can you scroll a bit to the right? Maybe there is a stray digit after the tab.

Comment: @Gerhardh You are right. I found them there at the right corner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. It is the out steam that cuts off the first character of the next line

Answer (score 2):

It is printing correctly, but because of the online compiler cutting off the first digit (for some reason) you are unable to see it. If you click the 3rd button above the output screen (which will copy the output) and paste it into notepad you will see that your output is correct.

Comment: @Yossiri you are welcome! If you need help feel free to ask. If this solved your issue it would be appreciated if you can approve this answer on the left side with the grey tick and clicking on it. Enjoy coding !